# Python NLTK pos_tag not returning the correct part-of-speech tag

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

Having this:

```
text = word_tokenize("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

And running:

```
nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

I get:

```
[('The', 'DT'), ('quick', 'NN'), ('brown', 'NN'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumps', 'NNS'), ('over', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('lazy', 'NN'), ('dog', 'NN')]
```

This is incorrect. The tags for `quick brown lazy` in the sentence should be:

```
('quick', 'JJ'), ('brown', 'JJ') , ('lazy', 'JJ')
```

Testing this through their [online tool](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process) gives the same result; `quick`, `brown` and `fox` should be adjectives not nouns.

Comment: Using their example sentence "John's big idea isn't all that bad." located here: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html I see it does a great job and finds the adjectives, why is that ? Where do you suggest to look for another tagger?

Comment: These are unambiguous words and should have been tagged correctly. Try some other tagger for better results.

Comment: @faceoff I don't know any tagger for this task, but I just suggested to look for one in Doc!

Comment: You can use HMM tagger in NLTK. I have a self implementation of HMM tagger which correctly predicted the tags for your example sentence. I suppose it should work for you as well.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**In short**:

> NLTK is not perfect. In fact, no model is perfect.

**Note:**

As of NLTK version 3.1, default `pos_tag` function is no longer the [old MaxEnt English pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386224/what-created-maxent-treebank-pos-tagger-english-pickle).

It is now the **perceptron tagger** from [@Honnibal's implementation](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/perceptron.py), see [`nltk.tag.pos_tag`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/__init__.py#L87)

```
>>> import inspect
>>> print inspect.getsource(pos_tag)
def pos_tag(tokens, tagset=None):
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
    return _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger)
```

Still it's better but not perfect:

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> pos_tag("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".split())
[('The', 'DT'), ('quick', 'JJ'), ('brown', 'NN'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumps', 'VBZ'), ('over', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('lazy', 'JJ'), ('dog', 'NN')]
```

At some point, if someone wants `TL;DR` solutions, see https://github.com/alvations/nltk_cli

---

**In long**:

**Try using other tagger (see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/tree/develop/nltk/tag) , e.g.**:

- HunPos
- Stanford POS
- Senna

**Using default MaxEnt POS tagger from NLTK, i.e. `nltk.pos_tag`**:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))
[('The', 'DT'), ('quick', 'NN'), ('brown', 'NN'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumps', 'NNS'), ('over', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('lazy', 'NN'), ('dog', 'NN')]
```

**Using Stanford POS tagger**:

```
$ cd ~
$ wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-postagger-2015-04-20.zip
$ unzip stanford-postagger-2015-04-20.zip
$ mv stanford-postagger-2015-04-20 stanford-postagger
$ python
>>> from os.path import expanduser
>>> home = expanduser("~")
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
>>> _path_to_model = home + '/stanford-postagger/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger'
>>> _path_to_jar = home + '/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar'
>>> st = POSTagger(path_to_model=_path_to_model, path_to_jar=_path_to_jar)
>>> text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> st.tag(text.split())
[(u'The', u'DT'), (u'quick', u'JJ'), (u'brown', u'JJ'), (u'fox', u'NN'), (u'jumps', u'VBZ'), (u'over', u'IN'), (u'the', u'DT'), (u'lazy', u'JJ'), (u'dog', u'NN')]
```

**Using HunPOS** (NOTE: the default encoding is ISO-8859-1 not UTF8):

```
$ cd ~
$ wget https://hunpos.googlecode.com/files/hunpos-1.0-linux.tgz
$ tar zxvf hunpos-1.0-linux.tgz
$ wget https://hunpos.googlecode.com/files/en_wsj.model.gz
$ gzip -d en_wsj.model.gz 
$ mv en_wsj.model hunpos-1.0-linux/
$ python
>>> from os.path import expanduser
>>> home = expanduser("~")
>>> from nltk.tag.hunpos import HunposTagger
>>> _path_to_bin = home + '/hunpos-1.0-linux/hunpos-tag'
>>> _path_to_model = home + '/hunpos-1.0-linux/en_wsj.model'
>>> ht = HunposTagger(path_to_model=_path_to_model, path_to_bin=_path_to_bin)
>>> text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> ht.tag(text.split())
[('The', 'DT'), ('quick', 'JJ'), ('brown', 'JJ'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumps', 'NNS'), ('over', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('lazy', 'JJ'), ('dog', 'NN')]
```

**Using Senna** (Make sure you've the latest version of NLTK, there were some changes made to the API):

```
$ cd ~
$ wget http://ronan.collobert.com/senna/senna-v3.0.tgz
$ tar zxvf senna-v3.0.tgz
$ python
>>> from os.path import expanduser
>>> home = expanduser("~")
>>> from nltk.tag.senna import SennaTagger
>>> st = SennaTagger(home+'/senna')
>>> text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> st.tag(text.split())
[('The', u'DT'), ('quick', u'JJ'), ('brown', u'JJ'), ('fox', u'NN'), ('jumps', u'VBZ'), ('over', u'IN'), ('the', u'DT'), ('lazy', u'JJ'), ('dog', u'NN')]
```

---

**Or try building a better POS tagger**:

- Ngram Tagger: http://streamhacker.com/2008/11/03/part-of-speech-tagging-with-nltk-part-1/
- Affix/Regex Tagger: http://streamhacker.com/2008/11/10/part-of-speech-tagging-with-nltk-part-2/
- Build Your Own Brill (Read the code it's a pretty fun tagger, http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/brill.html), see http://streamhacker.com/2008/12/03/part-of-speech-tagging-with-nltk-part-3/
- Perceptron Tagger: https://honnibal.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/a-good-part-of-speechpos-tagger-in-about-200-lines-of-python/
- LDA Tagger: http://scm.io/blog/hack/2015/02/lda-intentions/

---

**Complains about `pos_tag` accuracy on stackoverflow include**:

- [POS tagging - NLTK thinks noun is adjective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529945/pos-tagging-nltk-thinks-noun-is-adjective)
- [python NLTK POS tagger not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786257/python-nltk-pos-tagger-not-behaving-as-expected)
- [How to obtain better results using NLTK pos tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146748/how-to-obtain-better-results-using-nltk-pos-tag)
- [pos_tag in NLTK does not tag sentences correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365557/pos-tag-in-nltk-does-not-tag-sentences-correctly)

**Issues about NLTK HunPos include**:

- [How do I tag textfiles with hunpos in nltk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088448/how-to-i-tag-textfiles-with-hunpos-in-nltk)
- [Does anyone know how to configure the hunpos wrapper class on nltk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091389/does-anyone-know-how-to-configure-the-hunpos-wrapper-class-on-nltk)

**Issues with NLTK and Stanford POS tagger include**:

- [trouble importing stanford pos tagger into nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344916/trouble-importing-stanford-pos-tagger-into-nltk)
- [Java Command Fails in NLTK Stanford POS Tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116495/java-command-fails-in-nltk-stanford-pos-tagger)
- [Error using Stanford POS Tagger in NLTK Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930328/error-using-stanford-pos-tagger-in-nltk-python)
- [How to improve speed with Stanford NLP Tagger and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322674/how-to-improve-speed-with-stanford-nlp-tagger-and-nltk)
- [Nltk stanford pos tagger error : Java command failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171298/nltk-stanford-pos-tagger-error-java-command-failed)
- [Instantiating and using StanfordTagger within NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555312/instantiating-and-using-stanfordtagger-within-nltk)
- [Running Stanford POS tagger in NLTK leads to "not a valid Win32 application" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647253/running-stanford-pos-tagger-in-nltk-leads-to-not-a-valid-win32-application-on)

Comment: Yeah yeah, no model is perfect, but this example is pretty disappointing. Considering all the technology that went into this "recommended" tagger, it's not unreasonable to expect more.

Comment: Nice demo of the alternatives, though.

Comment: It has been 3 years since the model is update, possibly we should raise this to `nltk-dev` google group: https://github.com/arne-cl/nltk-maxent-pos-tagger. And the model was created 7 years ago =( https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/__init__.py#L84

Comment: By the look of it `Stanford` and `Senna` are superior taggers, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, stanford and senna tagger are more complicated and lots of effort were put in to build the tools from both groups.

Comment: @alvas Thank you for the amazing answer! It's still (sadly) pretty relevant in 2017 as I have been working with NLTK in the past few months

Comment: @tech4242, genau. Given a larger annotated corpus, it might be possible to reach a better tagger's accuracy.

Comment: mmm..in one sentence it was correctly tagging "change" as verb whereas in another sentence it was incorrectly tagging "change" as noun! bizzare

Answer (score 2):

Solutions such as changing to the Stanford or Senna or HunPOS tagger will definitely yield results, but here is a much simpler way to experiment with different taggers that are also included within NLTK.

The default POS tagger in NTLK right now is the averaged perceptron tagger.  Here's a function that will opt to use the Maxent Treebank Tagger instead:

```
def treebankTag(text)
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    treebankTagger = nltk.data.load('taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle')
    return treebankTagger.tag(words)
```

I have found that the averaged perceptron pre-trained tagger in NLTK is biased to treating some adjectives as nouns, as in your example.  The treebank tagger has gotten more adjectives correct for me.

Comment: interesting but with this mode is "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." "jumps" tagged as a noun not a verb.

Answer (score 1):

```
def tagPOS(textcontent, taggedtextcontent, defined_tags):
    # Write your code here
    token = nltk.word_tokenize(textcontent)
    nltk_pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(token)
    
    unigram_pos_tag = nltk.UnigramTagger(model=defined_tags).tag(token)
    
    tagged_pos_tag = [ nltk.tag.str2tuple(word) for word in taggedtextcontent.split() ]
    
    return (nltk_pos_tags,tagged_pos_tag,unigram_pos_tag)
```