# unable to use stanford pos tagger in nltk python

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I have nltk installed on my system. But I am unable to use Stanford POS Tagger using the following code.

```
    from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordTagger
    st = StanfordTagger('bidirection-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger')
```

I have even tried the documented code.

```
    from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
    st = StanfordPOSTagger('english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger')
```

this error was popping.

```
NLTK was unable to find ! Set the CLASSPATH environment variable.
```

I already have stanford.py in my nltk module

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-nltk-pos-tag-not-returning-the-correct-part-of-speech-tag/30823202#30823202

Comment: you have to specify the `path_to_model` and `path_to_jar` when creating the `nltk.pos.stanford.POSTagger`

Comment: do i need to specify model and path to jar to the stanford jar folder of pos tagger

Comment: yes, you have to. Follow the e.g. from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-nltk-pos-tag-not-returning-the-correct-part-of-speech-tag/30823202#30823202

Comment: I am now getting error at this ->    st.tag(text.split())

Comment: do i have to use java 1.8  for the pos tagger to work . And thanks for the link.