# NLTK Red not recognised as an adjective

Tags: nltk, python-3.4, pos-tagger

The word 'red' is recognised as a verb.
I believe it's because it thinks it is, following the pattern.
In the pattern, a word with an '-ed' suffix is a verb...or something like that.

How can I make exceptions or fix this issue. It might occur with other words later.

```
def LanguageTokenize(read):
    read = word_tokenize(read)
    read = nltk.pos_tag(read)
    return read

>>> LanguageTokenize('the red cat')
 *returns [('the', 'DT'), ('red', 'VBN'), ('cat', 'NN')]
```

Comment: Welcome to Natural Language Processing, where things never work 100% they way you think they should! I wouldn't spend too much time trying to fix artificial sentences (or phrases) like that. Test the tools on real-world texts and see how they perform there. If you're not happy, you probably need to retrain. If you start defining exceptions for what you think is a corner case, you will never get to an end...

Comment: SpaCy.io seems to be able to recognise it, I can't use that though because I don't have Linux.
If it's not too obvious, you're not being much help.

Comment: Make sure to have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-nltk-pos-tag-not-returning-the-correct-part-of-speech-tag)

Comment: @DeePad On StackOverflow, comments are not answers--they do not have to be that much help, and can just be a person's observations.  So relax...if we jumped on people for everything, we might jump on them for tagging their posts "cat" and "red", eh?

Comment: Okay. And I couldn't come up with any other tags that did not require me to have a high Reputation Score to create new ones. Sorry...

Comment: What @Lenz said: Don't worry about piecemeal "improvements", you have more important things to do and language is endless. That said, the NLTK's POS tagger has about [twice the error rate](http://spacy.io/blog/part-of-speech-POS-tagger-in-python/) of some other free tools. So if you _need_ accuracy it's worth your trouble to look for something else-- and still you'll get errors every other sentence.

Comment: SpaCy.io is much better but errors occur when installing it or installing things I need to install it. Perhaps you might have a link to somewhere for how to set it up properly and make sure I encounter no errors during installation?

Comment: @DeePad, you should start a new question for that, providing more details on the errors you get. If it's about installation only, you should probably post it on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) rather than here.

Comment: The `red -> VBN` should disappear once this is complete: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1122