# Hunpos Tagger not giving any results

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I have been through all the posts on Hunpos Tagger here and have followed them by the word to make it work, but unfortunately, each word is getting POS tagged as '**None**'. Here is my code and output:

```
from nltk.tag.hunpos import HunposTagger
from nltk import word_tokenize

sentence = "Please turn off the computer and unplug the AC adaptor"
tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
tagger = HunposTagger('/home/arindam/EclipseWorkspace/Resources/HunPOSTagger/Models/en_wsj.model', '/home/arindam/EclipseWorkspace/Resources/HunPOSTagger/hunpos-1.0-linux/hunpos-tag')
print tagger.tag(tokens)
```

> [('Please', None), ('turn', None), ('off', None), ('the', None), ('computer', None), ('and', None), ('unplug', None), ('the', None), ('AC', None), ('adaptor', None)]

Can anyone help and let me know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you follow instructions on http://stackoverflow.com/a/30823202/610569 ? From your example sentence and following the instructions, I'm getting `[('Please', 'VB'), ('turn', 'VB'), ('off', 'RP'), ('the', 'DT'), ('computer', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('unplug', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('AC', 'NNP'), ('adaptor', 'NN')]`.

Comment: I suspect HunPOS can't find the model. Try moving the `en_wsj.model` to `/home/arindam/EclipseWorkspace/Resources/HunPOSTagger/ ` instead of `/home/arindam/EclipseWorkspace/Resources/HunPOSTagger/Models`.