# What is the most fast and accurate POS Tagger in Python (with a commercial license)?

Tags: python, pos-tagger

Which POS tagger is fast and accurate and has a license that allows it to be used for commercial needs? For testing, I used Stanford POS which works well but it is slow and I have a license problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nltk](https://nltk.org).

```
>>> import nltk
>>> text = nltk.word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)
[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'),
('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]
```

Explanation:

`word_tokenize` first correctly tokenizes a sentence into words. Also available is a [sentence tokenizer.](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt)

Then, `pos_tag` tags an array of words into the Parts of Speech.

[More information available here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html)  and [here.](https://nltk.org)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823202/1459669) for a long and detailed list of POS Taggers in Python.

> NLTK is not perfect. **In fact, no model is perfect.**

---

You may need to first run

```
>>> import nltk; nltk.download()
```

in order to load the tokenizer data.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some successful experience with a combination of nltk's Part of Speech tagging and textblob's. Both are open for the public (or at least have a decent public version available).

http://textanalysisonline.com/nltk-pos-tagging

https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/