# How to import Stanford POS Tagger

Tags: python, nltk, typeerror, stanford-nlp

I'm attempting to make use of the Stanford POS Tagger in Python.

```
home = 'U:/ManWin/My Documents/Research Project'
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger as POS_Tag
_path_to_model = home + '/stanford-postagger/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger' 
_path_to_jar = home + '/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar'
st = POS_Tag(path_to_model=_path_to_model, path_to_jar=_path_to_jar)
```

Have copied the last line from the answer here: [Python NLTK pos_tag not returning the correct part-of-speech tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-nltk-pos-tag-not-returning-the-correct-part-of-speech-tag)

Getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "U:\Python35\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 136, in __init__
    super(StanfordPOSTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path_to_model'
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Looks like you are instantiating the wrong class here. According to the answer for the question you link to, the import line looks like this: `from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger`. You are importing something called, `StanordPOSTagger` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the name of the parameter `path_to_model` has changed to `model_filename`. So, replace the last line with:

`st = POS_Tag(model_filename=_path_to_model, path_to_jar=_path_to_jar)`

Or since the parameters are in order, just write:

`st = POS_Tag(_path_to_model, _path_to_jar)`